# Preparing arbitrary two- and multi-qubit states with real amplitudes

Tags: circuit-construction

1. Is it correct that the following circuit can produce any two-qubit state with real amplitudes? (Meaning that for any set of the four real amplitudes there exists a set of angles...)

[image]

2. If so, should I generally expect that arbitrary state preparation algorithms (such as [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406176)) can be adapted to preparing real-amplitude states by replacing all the single-qubit rotations with $R_y$'s?

Comment: This paper might be helpful: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.01940.pdf Specifically see part 5 and 6 of Theorem 1.

Comment: Thanks KAJ226. The recommended paper seems very interesting and truly can improve my understanding.